# Embedding private key into application code in Android

Tags: android, ssl, private-key

In my application, I need to establish a **SSL connection**. Currently, I have a **BKS** type keystore file, but I don' t want to store it in my apk as a file. AFAIK private keys can be embedded within application code as a String or something and then they can be obfuscated. So my questions are;

1) Is it really possible and would it be more secure than storing it as a "mykey.bks" file in my assets folder?

2) How can I copy and paste the contents of my bks file to my application code and how can I access it to create a socket factory?

Thanks

Comment: If you put your private key in your code, it still ends up in the APK file... If your private key is not password protected, it is not very private anymore when you publish the APK (with the key in it), so you might want to think about it a little more...

Comment: @Veger Actually I think I need to make a decision between having a password for my key file or trust the obfuscation and you think password protection is more secure than obfuscation with string encryption, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to keep you private key private, or everyone is able to login into your secure service. (Hence the name *private key*)

The only way to keep it really private is to not pass it around to others. For example, one your provide the private key using the UI of the application. If this key is not present, the user is unable to access the service!

This seems impossible in your current situation, at least from what it understand of your question. So a *second best solution* is to password protect the key. But then you need to provide the password to your users, which is fairly the same as providing the key itself to your users (previous option)...

The worse option is to embed the key into your application/APK without it being password protected. Any adept user is able to retrieve the key, using the same algorithm as the application uses: Deobfuscation, downloading, reading a file, etc.

The conclude, it seems silly that your service requires a private key, and your pass the key to (all? of) your users. So everyone is able to connect to the service... Why do you need the private key to access the service?

In the end the choice of the method to provide the key is yours!

---

**UPDATE** (was too long for a comment)

The general idea when using keys is, that the client has a (custom generated) [private/public key-pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). next, the public key part is send to the service. And the client is able to authenticate using the private key (by proving that the client has indeed the private key part).

In your situation, you need to provide a method to send public keys to your storage/service. The problem is that you need to somehow verify that the public key belongs to a client you want to grant access. This could be manually verified by administrators... Otherwise anyone is still able create nonsense subscriptions.

To be more concrete for your own application. It could include a SSL public/private key-pair  generator. After a new key-pair is generated, the public key could be send to your service from the application.

The service need to get it authenticated, until that moment the client could connect to the service (using the non-authenticated key-pair) to a read-only (guest) subscription (for example).

Again, the choice of the actual implementation is yours, these are only pointers.

Comment: Our requirements say that we need to establish an SSL connection with mutual trust in order to connect to our servers. Otherwise, any people can connect and create nonsense subscriptions(publish/subscribe type service). So that we need to have a keystore somewhere and I want it to be secure. My question is, what is the best practice to hold/reference the keystore? Thanks for your answer BTW :)

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Is it really possible and would it be more secure than storing it as a "mykey.bks" file in my assets folder?

Answer is no, because any one can extract assets folder from APK easily using APK **Decompiler Tools**

Solution:

**a).** put your `mykey.bks` file on secure server

**b).**  secure server url using  JNI by creating a simple class in C++ or C with getter methods and which return server URL at runtime(To avoid extract file url from apk)

**c).**  download *"mykey.bks"* file at runtime when u need to use in application and delete it when user close your Application

Comment: I guess that everyone can download the the private key? So this is just another obfuscation method... The idea of a private key is that it is private (ie not available to anyone), so protecting it with a password is the only way to go, IMHO.

Comment: @Veger: how every one download private key?

Comment: Same way the application does, using the the JNI code to grab the URL to the secure server and then download it. It is another form of obfuscation, but it still is.